# Return record or null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query, what this does it return a conversation history between two users as well as their profile picture.

```
SELECT m.Id, p.Id [SenderId], mr.RecipientId, p.Username, m.[Message], p.LastLoggedIn, p.LoggedIn, up.PhotoId, @UserId [UserId], m.SentDate
FROM [User].[User_Profile] p
INNER JOIN [User].[User_Details] d on p.Id = d.UserId
INNER JOIN [User].[User_Photos] up on p.Id = up.UserId
INNER JOIN [MailBox].[Message] m on p.Id = m.SenderId
INNER JOIN [MailBox].[MessageRecipient] mr on m.Id = mr.MessageId
WHERE 
   (p.id = @UserId or p.id = @SenderId) 
AND 
    up.IsProfilePic = 1

AND (mr.RecipientId = @UserId and m.SenderId = @SenderId or m.SenderId = @UserId and mr.RecipientId = @SenderId)

AND p.ProfileStatus = 4

AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT UserId FROM [User].[Block_List] 
                                      WHERE DateBlocked is not null 
                                           AND(
                                              (BlockedById = @UserId and UserId = p.Id) 
                                           OR 
                                              (BlockedById = p.Id and UserId = @UserId) 
                                           )) 

AND mr.DeletedDate is null

order by m.Id
```

As you can see I have specified where up.IsProfilePic = 1 this works fine if both user's have set a profile picture but if either of them do not set a profile picture then I need to return null for that particular user if not both, because at present it will only return 1 user due to the other not having a profile picture set.

Now the user photo table could consist of 10+ photos per user or even 0 if they haven't uploaded any.  The photoId I'm interested in is where IsProfilePic = 1 if this isn't set or no photos exist for that particular user then return null for PhotoId but I can think for the life of me how to achieve this, I did try saying

```
isnull(up.PhotoId, 'NoPhoto')
```

Within the select statement but that didn't seem to work either, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a left join on the photos table and put the condition in the `on` clause:

```
LEFT JOIN [User].[User_Photos] up ON p.Id = up.UserId AND up.IsProfilePic = 1
```

This will match the profile picture if there is one, otherwise you get null values for the fields of that table for that record.

By putting the condition in the `on` clause it will limit the records that are joined instead or limiting the entire result.

Answer (score 0):

why on earth do you have both @UserId and @SenderId?  you should have 1 and rename the alias p to pSender, and rename up to upSender (because you have joined it on m.SenderId, you should make the alias table name clear that its the photo for your sender.

also your User_Photos table could be LEFT JOIN not inner join, else when there are zero records your query will return nothing. 
INNER JOIN [User].[User_Photos]

and put [MailBox].[Message] m  as your first FROM item, because it is the most important.

try those things, and then see how you go.

Comment: An answer provided before yours solved my problem, I've just gone through and done the suggestion you had provided to make it clearer. Thanks for your input.